Add overlay above GridView in flutter
I'm trying to add an overlay to a GridView in Flutter. The effect I want to achieve is for my grid to initially appear blocked, and then, for example after a button click, remove the overlay and show the underlying content. However, every attempt I make results in a full-screen overlay or I must declare a fixed height but for a GridView that is adaptive is not a great choice.
This is what I am trying to do:

But my widgets look like this:

That's my code:
Stack(
 children: [
    GridView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    crossAxisSpacing: 12,
    mainAxisSpacing: 12), 
    itemCount: myList.length,
    itemBuilder: (
       context,
       index,
    ) {
    return Container(
       width: 50, 
      height:50,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
  ),
    
}),

Center(
   child: Container(
   width: double.infinity, 
   color: Colors.grey,
  ),
)],
),

Thank you all

You almost there:
You can just wrap that container with positioned widget to force it to cover the whole stack:
Positioned(

// how far is the container from each side

left : 0, 
top : 0,
bottom : 0,
right : 0,

child: Container(color: Colors.grey),

)

If you got the above snippet of code, it's the same as that named constructor:
Positioned.fill(
child: Container(color: Colors.grey)
)

This named constructor just use a zero for each attribute top , left, right and bottom.

Best Answer, short but straight to the point, thank you!

@FrancoRomano , u r wlcm

actually there is a Widget called Overlay which is made for this:
Here's a code :
class OverlayExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverlayExampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverlayExampleWidget> createState() => _OverlayExampleWidgetState();
}

class _OverlayExampleWidgetState extends State<OverlayExampleWidget> {
  bool isLocked = true;
  void unLockContent() {
    setState(() {
      isLocked = !isLocked;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Overlay(
        initialEntries: <OverlayEntry>[
          OverlayEntry(
            builder: (context) {
              return Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 12,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                  ),
                  itemCount: 30,
                  itemBuilder: (
                    context,
                    index,
                  ) {
                    return Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          OverlayEntry(
            builder: (context) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  unLockContent();
                },
                child: isLocked
                    ? Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        bottom: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.lock,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : null,
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

You can use the same Positioned with Stack also
Hope that's help !!!

Try this version; it might resolve your problem:
The GridView is wrapped in a Visibility widget that controls its visibility based on the boolean variable isOverlayVisible. The overlay is implemented using a semi-transparent Container positioned at the same level as the GridView. A button (an ElevatedButton in this case) is positioned using the Positioned widget to toggle the isOverlayVisible boolean, thus controlling the visibility of the overlay.
bool isOverlayVisible = true; // Define a boolean to toggle the overlay

Stack(
  children: [
    // Your GridView wrapped in a Visibility widget to control its visibility
    Visibility(
      visible: !isOverlayVisible,
      child: GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          crossAxisSpacing: 12,
          mainAxisSpacing: 12,
        ),
        itemCount: myList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            // Your grid item content here
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    // Semi-transparent overlay container
    Container(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), // Adjust opacity as needed
    ),
    // Your button or trigger to toggle the overlay
    Positioned(
      top: 20, // Adjust position as needed
      left: 20, // Adjust position as needed
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isOverlayVisible = !isOverlayVisible; // Toggle overlay visibility
          });
        },
        child: Text(isOverlayVisible ? 'Show Content' : 'Hide Content'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);



